# How to configure the socket permission for Nginx + php5-fpm?

Tags: nginx, php

Nginx runs under user `www-data`. For php5-fpm pool, I have two websites namely, **website1** and **website2** with the following configuration in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/`:

**website1 config in fpm pool**

```
 user = website1
 group = website1
 listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-website1.sock
 listen.owner = website1
 listen.group = website1
 listen.mode = 0666
```

**website2 config in fpm pool**

```
 user = website2
 group = website2
 listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-website2.sock
 listen.owner = website2
 listen.group = website2
 listen.mode = 0666
```

The above configuration works fine as it creates the Unix Socket files with `666` permission. But, ideally I want to change `listen.mode` to 0660 to create the same permission for my socket.

My problem is, if I change `listen.mode` to `0660` and then restart nginx/php5-fpm, I get 502 Bad Gateway due to permission issue.

**EDIT**

I have gone through similar question before in SO (including the one referred by @Mario, however, I am more looking for a solution with configuration suitable for multiple websites (server blocks) keeping their individual security intact...

Comment: `listen.owner = website1` needs to be the user id your `nginx` webserver process runs with. Only `owner=` and `group=` pertain the the FPMs uid.

Comment: @Mario Sorry.. can you expand the comment little more? Should I assign `listen.owner` and `listen.group` both to `nginx` userid and group?

Comment: Yes, set them to `www-data`.

Comment: @Mario But if all the sockets are under same user, doesn't it mean then that `website1` can redirect its request to `website2` socket and vice-versa and possibly breach security in some way?

Comment: Depends on your `nginx` configuration. Neither uid `website1` not `website2` however will have access to the FPM socket when it's owned by `www-data`, so can't initiate a local FCGI process on behalf of the other account. If you wanna separate the sockets, you'd need two distinct `nginx` processes (which was only necessary when both accounts can run arbitrary CGI scripts under `www-data`).